# What are the limits on the Google Data API?

Tags: google-data-api

I'm using the Google Analytics API (via Java) to pull out data from Analytics. However, I keep getting kicked back the message "Insufficient quota to proceed."

I have seen the documented limits at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html#quota but these seem entirely non-factual. I am using a packet logger and can confirm I do not have more than 4 concurrent requests per IP and that I am not sending more than 10 requests per second from each IP address.

What are the actual limits of this API?

Answer (score 1):

This of course being subject to change, according to
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataGettingStarted.html#quota_policy
the quota for registered applications are:

> General Analytics API quotas. These apply to both the Analytics APIs,
> i.e., Management API and Core Reporting API.
>
> ```
> * 50,000 requests per project per day
> * 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP
> ```
>
> Quotas specific to Core Reporting API
>
> ```
> * 10,000 requests per profile per day
> * 10 concurrent requests per profile
> ```
>
> For unregistered applications, we provide a very low grace quota to
> accommodate a small amount of testing.
>
> If quota is exceeded, Google Analytics API returns an error for
> additional requests: HTTP status code 403 Forbidden and a message
> indicating that the specific account has insufficient quota to
> proceed. See the terms of service for more information.